# Simplifying an 'if' statement with bool()?

Tags: python-3.x

I am a beginner python user. how would I shorten this? my pylint was complaining.

```
def eat_ghost(power_pellet_active, touching_ghost):
    if power_pellet_active is True and touching_ghost is True:
        return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to write `is True` because what this does is check if `True is True`. You can also return the result of the `x and y` directly, it is again a boolean value.

```py
def eat_ghost(power_pellet_active, touching_ghost):
    return power_pellet_active and touching_ghost
```

Comment: thats only half true (see my answer)

Answer (score 0):

`if expression` evaluates to `if bool(expression)`.

but you should be aware that `bool(expression)` is not equal to `expression is True`. `bool("any non empty string")` is `True` but  `"any non empty string" is True` is `False`

Comment: oh yes, I was confused myself. I changed it ^